# How to call Background progressChanged while getting data from method which returns collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have method which retrieves data. I am calling that method inside background worker DoWork. I wanted to display the progress on UI. How do I show the progress (time taken to execute method from 0 to 100) in percentage. SO that I can report progress using bgWorker_ProgressChanged

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    MyCollection = GetReportData();            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to specify that you want to be able to report progress:

```
bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

Then, modify your `DoWork` event to actually report progress. You're currently getting all of your data at once, which doesn't lend itself well to showing progress *as* you're getting data.

You'll need to break down your `GetReportData()` into manageable pieces.

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var bg = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    var myCollection = new List<SomeClass>();

    while(/* somehow test whether there's more data to get */)
    {
        myCollection.AddRange(GetSomeMoreReportData());

        bg.ReportProgress(0);  // or pass a valid "percentage" if you can calculate it
    }

    // Don't access the UI from a background thread.
    // The safest thing you can do is pass the final data to the RunWorkerCompleted event
    e.Result = myCollection;
}

void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // You're back in the UI thread, update your ProgressBar
}

void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    List<SomeClass> result = (List<SomeClass>)e.Result;

    // You're back in the UI thread, update your UI with the data
}
```

This is all pretty generic, and I've made some assumptions about your environment. Give this a try and modify it for your situation... if you play around with it a bit and get stuck, then post back here.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am aware of this approach but my concern is that I get my collection from a class library, hence I can't break it down further in more pieces.